# Turning Some(List()) into None

Tags: list, scala, option-type

I have optional lists, for example:

`val optionalEmptyList = Option(List[String]())`

`val optionalNonEmptyList = Option(List[String]("1","2"))`

And I would like to replace the optional empty lists by None while keeping the optional non-empty lists as-is.

I came up with the following solution:

`optionalEmptyList.flatMap(l => if (l.isEmpty) None else Option(l))`

`optionalNonEmptyList.flatMap(l => if (l.isEmpty) None else Option(l))`

It works but seems convoluted.  Any simpler solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
optionalEmptyList.filter(_.nonEmpty)
```